# Not able to write logs to Azure Application Insights in Controller using Serilog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I have a .net6 web API, I am trying to write logs to Azure application insights. It works when I try to write in Program.cs. But it's not writing when I am trying to write in the Controller action method.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .Build();
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        logger.Information("Hello, world!!!!!");

            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

**Controller**:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Info");
        _logger.LogTrace("Trace");
        _logger.LogCritical("Critical");
        _logger.LogDebug("Debug");
        _logger.LogError("Error");
        _logger.LogWarning("Warning");

        Log.Information("Information!");
        Log.Warning("Warning!");
        Log.Error("Error!");
        Log.Debug("Debug!");

        Log.Logger.Error("Information!!");
        Log.Logger.Warning("Warning!!");
        Log.Logger.Error("Error!!");
        Log.Logger.Debug("Debug!!");
        Log.Logger.Warning("Warning!!");
```

**Appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Sample"
    }
  }
}
```

I have set my connection string in the environment variable.

These are the Nuget packages along with the versions.

[image]

**Azure app insights**

[image]

Comment: You have set connection string in environment variables and adding configuration from appsettings.json. Please check the code in program.cs

Comment: You are not using the retrieved value anywhere.

Comment: @Harshitha I have removes that code. that was just to check whether I am getting the value of the environment variable for debugging purposes. 
And If you notice I am able to see Hello, World!!!!! in logs, but not the ones which are written in the controller. hope it makes clear now.

Comment: Hope you are executing the correct httpget method.

Comment: @Harshitha yes, I have put breakpoint and I’m able to hit

Comment: Ok..checking from my end with same code.Will let you know once I get the message.

Comment: If you set Serilog to log to console, did you find the information? It seems to me that you miss the Logger configuration for .NET `builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) ...` .

Comment: @RobertoFerraris sorry didn't get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As you mentioned, Even I have set `Application Insights Connection String` in Visual Studio Environment Variable.

[image]

- Initially with your code Iam able to log only the messages from `Program.cs` file.

[image]

- After making few changes in `Program.cs`  only Iam able to see the messages from `Controller`.

***`Progarm.cs` file:***

```cs
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters;

var ConnStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING");
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
           .Build();
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(ConnStr, new TraceTelemetryConverter())
    .CreateLogger();

logger.Information("Hello, world ");

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);

var app = builder.Build();
```

***Message from `Program.cs`:***

[image]

***Message from `Controller`:***

[image]

[image]

***My `Controller.cs`:***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Serilog;

namespace SerilogInsights.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Info..");
            _logger.LogTrace("Trace from Controller");
            _logger.LogCritical("Critical trace");
            _logger.LogDebug("Debug message logs");
            _logger.LogError("Error message");
            _logger.LogWarning("Warning message");

            Log.Information("Information!");
            Log.Warning("Warning!");
            Log.Error("Error!");
            Log.Debug("Debug!...");

            Log.Logger.Error("Information!! ...");
            Log.Logger.Warning("Warning!!");
            Log.Logger.Error("Error!!");
            Log.Logger.Debug("Debug!!");
            Log.Logger.Warning("Warning!!");
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you I’ll try with your code. One thing can we use InstrumentationKey in place of ConnectionString?

Comment: Yes,we can use Instrumentation key as well.But in MsDoc it says Instrumentation key is going to be deprecated.

Comment: @SPT I understand your concern. I am yet to try the solution provided.

Comment: @Harshitha I have made the changes as you suggested. But it is still not writing logs from the controller. Can you show me your controller code?

Comment: I have not made any chanegs to the default code, just added the logs same as your's.Please check the edit in the answer.

Comment: Just wait for few minutes and refresh the Transaction Search.

Comment: Make sure you are selecting the `UTC/GMT` to avoid time differences. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDtPd.png)

Comment: Its been 15-20 mins, I am still not able to see :( @Harshitha

Comment: @Harshitha can you show me your appsettings.json as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253146/discussion-between-harshitha-and-vivek-nuna).

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of this line? var connStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"); so that it can consider the environment variable by it self if not set in appsettings.json file?

Comment: I am unaccepting this answer because it’s not answering my question completely. I don’t want to use the ConnectionString in my C# code. I want it to be automatically considered from environment variable

Comment: Add `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` and check once.

Comment: I followed this line by line several times and could not get the logging to Azure Application Insights working

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the code in `Program.cs` doesn't configure Serilog properly.

If you follow [Configuration Basics - Serilog Wiki](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics) you must set `Serilog.Log` to a logger.

So try to change

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
  .CreateLogger();
```

to

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
  .CreateLogger();
```

In this way `Log` methods will work. **But**, you must use `Log` class and couldn't use `ILogger` injection, since Serilog is not set as "the default logger" method.

I suggest to use [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#serilogaspnetcore---) package and setup your application as written in the README.

```
using Serilog;
// This provide logger functionality  for startup
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration() 
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

try
{
    Log.Information("Starting web application");

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Host.UseSerilog(); 

    // ...
    
    var app = builder.Build();

    // ...
    
    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```